# Handling null values when case statement return null postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case

I have a table called **check_n** where I have city & value

I wrote a query which has CASE statements in it. Below is my query

```
select city,
       CASE when (value/10)::integer = 2 
       then 2 END as a,
       CASE when (value/10)::integer = 5 
       then 5 END as b,
       CASE when (value/10)::integer = 3 
       then 3 END as c
from check_n;
```

Attaching the output in below image[image]

I want output as below:

```
city, a, b, c
glb, 2, 5, 3
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm using Postgresql 9.5

Also How to use the function if I have another table chck_n like :

```
 city |  fact  | value 
------+--------+-------
glb  | male   | 22000
glb  | female | 23000
glb  | total  | 45000
```

And I want to use this query:

```
SELECT city,
      CASE WHEN fact = 'male'
           THEN value
      END as males,
      CASE WHEN fact= 'female'
           THEN value
      END as females,
      CASE WHEN fact ='total'
           THEN value
      END as total
FROM chck_n;
```

Comment: Your expected output makes no sense.  How can `value` simultaneously be equal to 2, 5, and 3?  Please show us sample data, along with the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one result per city, you could proceed like this:

```
SELECT city,
       CASE WHEN 2 =ANY (array_agg((value/10)::integer))
            THEN 2
       END as a,
       CASE WHEN 5 =ANY (array_agg((value/10)::integer))
            THEN 5
       END as b,
       CASE WHEN 3 =ANY (array_agg((value/10)::integer))
            THEN 3
       END as c
FROM check_n
GROUP BY city;

 city | a | b | c 
------+---+---+---
 glb  | 2 | 5 | 3
(1 row)
```

Comment: hey, How if I have another table chck_n like :
 city |  fact  | value 
------+--------+-------
glb  | male   | 22000
glb  | female | 23000
glb  | total  | 45000

And I want to use this query:
SELECT city,
      CASE WHEN fact = 'male'
           THEN value
      END as males,
      CASE WHEN fact= 'female'
           THEN value
      END as females,
      CASE WHEN fact ='total'
           THEN value
      END as total
FROM chck_n;

Comment: If it is a similar problem, do it similarly. If it is a different case, write a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume with your data set:

```
with ds as (
select city,
       CASE when (value/10)::integer = 2 
       then 2 END as a,
       CASE when (value/10)::integer = 5 
       then 5 END as b,
       CASE when (value/10)::integer = 3 
       then 3 END as c
from check_n)
select distinct city, max(a)a, max(b) b, max(c) c
from ds
group by city
```